# Sort multidimensional array of objects by nested property value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I am trying to arrange my array (below) by [date], but to no avail as of yet.

```
Array
(
    [0] => gapiReportEntry Object
        (
            [metrics:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
                (
                    [uniquepageviews] => 0
                    [pageviews] => 0
                    [visits] => 0
                    [visitors] => 0
                )

            [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20131009
                )

        )

    [1] => gapiReportEntry Object
        (
            [metrics:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
                (
                    [uniquepageviews] => 1
                    [pageviews] => 1
                    [visits] => 1
                    [visitors] => 1
                )

            [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20131026
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Already tried this? http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Tried multisort already, doesn't seem to work unless i'm doing it wrong.
foreach($ga->getResults() as $i => $result) {
 
 $dates[$i] = $result->getDate();

}

array_multisort($dates, SORT_ASC, $ga->getResults());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard php usort function to do it :

```php
$array = usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->dimensions->date,  $b->dimensions->date);
}):
```

Notice I use a closure here (see http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php))

Answer (score 0):

Considering the array is called $array, try this code:

```
$dates = array();
foreach($array as $v)
    $dates[] = $v['dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private'];

asort($dates);

$sorted_array = array();
foreach($dates as $k => $v)
    $sorted_array[$k] = $array[$k];
```

You will have the result in the $sorted_array variable.